# jquery is not working with IE 8

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer

i am trying to implement toggle function with a table row. Everything is going fine except in IE8. The script which i was used is given below.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tr:first-child").show();

        $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
            $(this).next("tr").each(function (){ this.toggle()});
            $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
        });
        //$("#report").jExpand();
    });
</script>
```

somebody please help me..

Jessica

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: when i click on the row, the toggle function(hide and show contents) not working..

Comment: i made it $(this).next("tr").toggle(); but not working (only in IE 8), is there any solution ? please help me.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick Craver, Pekka, EMMERICH for helping me on this issue.. Its working now..

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap ([`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)) your `this` (which is just a DOM element inside that loop, not a jQuery object) to have access to [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$(this).toggle()
```

But there's no need for the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop here, this:

```
$(this).next("tr").each(function (){ $(this).toggle()});
```

can just be this:

```
$(this).next("tr").toggle();
```

And it'll operate on *all* of the elements found...even though there will be only one here.

---

Issue #2 is the fact that IE8 specifically thinks the next row is *always* visibile (this is a bug in the **jQuery 1.3.2** implementation you're using).  You have 2 options here, the quick fix is to re-write it like this:

```
$("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
    var show = $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up").hasClass("up");
    $(this).next("tr").toggle(show);
});
```

[You can see that working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/a3EAz/).  Or a better solution to me, **upgrade to the latest jQuery (1.4.3)**, [you can test your current code here against it](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/a3EAz/1/), working in IE8 as well.

Comment: later it was like that. butTHAT TOO FAILS.

Comment: @jessi - Do you have an example page?  We can't say what will fix your issue 100% without the markup, but the problem I describe/showed how to solve above did for 100% sure throw an error.

Comment: yes, i got the example from the below URL http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows/

Comment: @jessi - The issue is with height detection in IE8 with jQuery 1.3.2 thinking the row is *already* visible, this was changed in later versions, you can either change your code or update jQuery...I've elaborated on both above in an updated asnwer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick Craver, Pekka, EMMERICH for helping me on this issue.. Its working now..

Comment: @jessi - welcome :) be sure to [accept answers](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) on this and future questions :)

Answer (score 0):

In your line:

```
$(this).next("tr").each(function (){ this.toggle()});
```

Try changing it to:

```
$(this).next("tr").each(function (){ $(this).toggle()});
```

I've had this problem before on some browsers not being able to differentiate between this and $(this).

So you'll get:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
  $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
  $("#report tr:first-child").show();

  $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
    $(this).next("tr").each(function (){ $(this).toggle()});
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
  });
});
```

Comment: This isn't a browser specific problem, this would *never* work.

Comment: oop, you're right. I think when I was having the problem it may have been a little different.

Comment: i made it $(this).next("tr").toggle(); but not working (only in IE 8), is there any solution ? please help me.

Comment: well I've copied your code, applied the fix we talked about and it works.